# Exception when working with composite gradle build

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle 6.1 setup with two gradle build files. If I connect them in an Intellij composite build, and reload the gradle configuration of the master project, this exception is shown in the build-view in intelliJ.

Where can I see, which assertion failed?

```
exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.createModule(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.createModule(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:344)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:725)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:708)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:278)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleBuildSrcProjectsResolver.handleBuildSrcProject(GradleBuildSrcProjectsResolver.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleBuildSrcProjectsResolver.discoverAndAppendTo(GradleBuildSrcProjectsResolver.java:152)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Does your Gradle composite build work outside of IntelliJ? Can you perhaps provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I have this problem with this project: https://github.com/didinj/grails3-angular5-profiles-cru. Import the "server" module, not the parent.

Comment: Thank you both, but the simple examples do not create the issue and the second suggestion was no solution for me, as I already imported the right project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is related issue under investigation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228368

Comment: I know, it does not solve the issue for me, but this was important for my peace of mind. ;-)